MongoDB 4.4 & the allowdiskuse option
Is there a way in MongoDB 4.4 to set allowdiskuse to default to true always? I know this is the default behaviour post MongoDB 6.0.
Upgrading to 6.0+ is unfortunately not option at this time.
The manual does not explain how to achieve this.

But you are aware that MongoDB 4.4 became End-Of-Life in February 2024?

No - which is mentioned by the link in @dododo's answer
